# PHP & JQuery question

Tags: php, jquery

I was wondering is there a way I can have my page display a delete message after the php code has done the deletion and then have Jquery fade out the message after about 5 seconds. If so how would my JQuery code look like? An example would help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. If your message has an ID of 'delete-message' then you can use the following code:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#delete-message').fadeOut();
    },5000);
});
```

That will set a timeout of 5 seconds once the page has loaded, and after that 5 seconds, it will fade out the element with the ID 'delete-message'.

Comment: I think you can do `$('#delete-message').delay(5000).fadeOut();` instead of using `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using document ready funtion

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#delete-message').fadeOut();
      alert('test');
    },3000);
});
```